# How does Qt handle limited throughput in the event/message queue?

Tags: c++, qt, event-handling, signals-slots

I have a `QTimer` set up to `timeout()` periodically, and my slot to handle it could potentially have a lot to do because the dataset is user-defined with no explicit limit.  At some point, the exact details of which depend on the system that it's running on, it might take longer to process than the timer is set for.  What happens then?

1. Do the events continue to pile up at 100% CPU load until the queue overflows and the app crashes?
2. Are events discarded while there's still an unserviced one of the same type, meaning that I'll still have 100% CPU load but never overflow the queue?
3. Specific to `QTimer`: Is it not restarted until the slot returns, meaning that not only will the queue never overflow but I'll actually have some idle time in between as well?

---

### Edit Oct 4 '17:

I found this answer to a similar question that seems to suggest that, regardless of platform, QTimer events simply don't "stack up", even if it does take too long to service them:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17077411/3491308

If I interpret that answer correctly, there's a timestamp (or equivalent) for each QTimer, and something like `if(now > timestamp) { timestamp = now + period; emit timeout(); }` in the QTimer's event loop.  Thus, no more events until the slot returns, and then only one...provided that the slot uses the same event loop.

In that case, my CPU load will probably approach 100% as the processing slows down (and any timing based on that "sample rate" will be a bit off), but the app will never crash.  Is that true?

Comment: I find the event loop often stalling, especially on embedded device while processing messages coming too fast. That is especially a case for the app with QML UI and QML_BAD_GUI_RENDER_LOOP set (if that not set then there plenty of other "surprises"). Messages coming fast, like video frames and it often clashes with switching UI to other form etc. Whether or not  there is 100% CPU load on that thread is another question... there is a "sync rate" and other factors. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html

Comment: @AlexanderVX  Stalling?  Like I still have events coming in and all the slots have returned, but I still don't call any more?  If that's true, I'd probably call it a bug in Qt.

Comment: Qt is not ideal of course and I do certain hacks for the embedded platform not avoid pushing video frames faster than refresh rate (which is lower than Qt specifies). In our case the app runs in a special context called Qt Auto. The PC version behaves much better and the context there is very different. It answers your question to degree but it needs to be accurate with the answer and not to answer like "it feels like there and there".

Comment: @AlexanderVX  I'm definitely using the PC version, on Ubuntu Linux, with thoughts about migrating to a 'Pi.  As far as I know, that migration shouldn't change anything, right?  Anyway, I don't see an answer in what you said, so maybe you can clarify?

Comment: I have no proper answer to 1/2/3. It is all Qt/platform specific. But overall, yes, Qt sometimes shows threads event loops stalling. That is not necessarily 100% CPU load, though. My observation is that if you pile too many events too frequently and event handlers do some processing the app may end up in irresponsive state. And when you stumble upon such behavior you can apply necessary fixes like I watch QML refresh handler to prevent excessive frame update. And of course Ubuntu on PC would be far better than Raspberry PI.